# Convert RAW files with DCRAW while maintaining ICC profiles

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, icc, camera-raw

I would like to decode my Canon EOS 6D camera RAWs using [DCRAW](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/).

My problem is that I want to retain the original picture style of the photo (including the ICC profile) during the RAW conversion to JPEG format.

I am using the following script:

`for i in *.CR2; do newname=${i%CR2}jpg; dcraw -t 0 -c -w -o 1 -v -h "$i" | cjpeg -quality 95 -optimize -progressive > "$newname"; exiftool -overwrite_original -tagsFromFile "$i" "$newname"; done`

I know that I could test the `-p` option if I can generate the ICC profile from a chart photo processed with `dcraw -4 -o 0`. However, for other reasons I'm not able to do that.

How can I convert RAW files into JPEG that maintain the original style of the photo (e.g. "landscape", "portrait")? Do you think it's possible? Is there another, better way to do the same thing?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited to photo.stackexchange.com? However, do *not* double-post there! Instead, flag this question and let a moderator know that you'd like it to be migrated.